# Exception caught by gesture 'then' was called on null

Tags: flutter

I faced this error when I tried to insert image

"The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'then' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: then(Closure: (dynamic) => Null)"

Below is my code. Hope someone can help me with it. I have no idea how to solve it. Thank you.

```html
// ignore_for_file: import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe, unrelated_type_equality_checks

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dparking/model/user_model.dart';
import 'package:dparking/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class RegistrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegistrationScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RegistrationScreen> createState() => _RegistrationScreenState();
}

class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen> {

  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // form key
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  // editing Controller
  final nameEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final emailEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final confirmPasswordEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final phoneNumberEditingController = TextEditingController();
  XFile? _logo;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Name field
    final nameField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: nameEditingController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      validator: (value) {
        RegExp regex = RegExp(r'^.{3,}$');
        if(value!.isEmpty){
          return ("Name cannot be Empty");
        }
        if(!regex.hasMatch(value))
        {
          return ("Enter Valid Name(Min. 3 Character");
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (value)
      {
        nameEditingController.text = value!;
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
        hintText: "Name",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );

    // Email field
    final emailField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: emailEditingController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      validator: (value)
      {
        if(value!.isEmpty)
        {
          return ("Please Enter Your Email");
        }
        // reg expression for email validation
        if(!RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z]").hasMatch(value))
        {
          return("Please Enter a valid email");
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (value)
      {
        emailEditingController.text = value!;
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.mail),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
        hintText: "Email",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );

    // Password field
    final passwordField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: passwordEditingController,
      obscureText: true,
      validator: (value) {
        RegExp regex = RegExp(r'^.{6,}$');
        if(value!.isEmpty){
          return ("Password is required for login");
        }
        if(!regex.hasMatch(value))
        {
          return ("Enter Valid Password(Min. 6 Character");
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (value)
      {
        passwordEditingController.text = value!;
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.vpn_key),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
        hintText: "Password",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );

    // Confirm Password field
    final confirmPasswordField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: confirmPasswordEditingController,
      obscureText: true,
      validator: (value)
      {
        if(confirmPasswordEditingController.text.length !=
            passwordEditingController.text){
          return "Password Does Not Match";
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (value)
      {
        confirmPasswordEditingController.text = value!;
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.vpn_key),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
        hintText: "Confirm Password",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );

    //signup button
    final signupButton = Material(
      elevation: 5,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      child: MaterialButton(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        onPressed: () {
          signUp(emailEditingController.text, passwordEditingController.text);
        },
        child: const Text("SignUp", textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
        ),
      ),
    );



    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.red),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 300,
                        child: Image.asset("assets/images/DParking.png",
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      nameField,
                      const SizedBox(height: 30),
                      emailField,
                      const SizedBox(height: 30),
                      passwordField,
                      const SizedBox(height: 30),
                      confirmPasswordField,
                      const SizedBox(height: 30),
                      InkWell(
                       onTap: (){
                          _pickImage().then((value){  //i think the error is here
                            setState((){
                              _logo = value;
                            });
                          });
                        },
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 4,
                          child: _logo==null ? const SizedBox(
                            height: 100,
                            width: 250,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text('Insert Identification Card'),
                            ),
                          ):SizedBox(
                            height: 100,
                            width: 250,
                            child: Image.file(File(_logo!.path),)
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 30),
                      signupButton,
                      const SizedBox(height: 30),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }

  void signUp(String email, String password) async
  {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      await _auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
          .then((value) => {postDetailsToFirestore()})
          .catchError((e) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e!.message);
      });
    }
  }

    postDetailsToFirestore() async {
    // call firestore
    //call user model
    //send value

      FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      User? user = _auth.currentUser;

      UserModel userModel = UserModel();

      userModel.email = user!.email;
      userModel.uid = user.uid;
      userModel.name = nameEditingController.text;
      
      await firebaseFirestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .set(userModel.toMap());
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Account created successfully");
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          (context),
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()),
              (route) => false);

  }

}

_pickImage() {
}
```

Comment: put variables before build method

Comment: late Widget variable; @override
  build(BuildContext context)
I suppose this is what you mean but the error still remain.

Comment: I mean, you are declaring variables (`final nameField = TextFormField(`) inside build method , try with putting them outside the build method.

Comment: I move the whole (final nameField = TextFormField( ) outside build method but error show 'nameEditingController' cant be accessed in an initializer

Comment: Implementation of _pickImage is missing.

Comment: You really should just use `async`/`await` instead of using `.then` (and `.catchError`).  Mixing them is usually bad style.  If you're absolutely set on using `.then` for some reason, you could just use `?.then(...)` if the object might be `null`.